# Woocommerce showing custom backorder message on updating the cart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have custom code that's showing different backorder messages for products based on their tags. It's working perfectly on product page and cart, but I need it to show the custom messages in cart when qty>stock.

I tried playing with hooks (cart_update, qty_update) and rewriting the code to check qty of product but no luck. That's what I have rn:

```
function get_custom_availability_message($product, $quantity_required) {
    $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    $tags = wp_get_post_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_tag', array('fields' => 'slugs'));

    if ($quantity_required > $stock_quantity) {
        if (array_intersect(['eco', 'promienniki', 'star-trading'], $tags)) {
            return 'Czas wysyłki: 3-7 dni roboczych';
        } elseif (array_intersect(['g12', '5mm', 'm5'], $tags)) {
            return 'Czas wysyłki: 3-5 dni roboczych';
        }
        // Możesz dodać więcej warunków dla innych tagów
    }

    return null;
}

function custom_availability_logic($availability, $product) {
    $stock_status = $product->get_stock_status();

    $custom_message = get_custom_availability_message($product, 1);
    if ($custom_message) {
        return $custom_message;
    }

    if ($stock_status == 'instock') {
        return 'Na stanie: wysyłka w ciągu 48h';
    } elseif ($stock_status == 'onbackorder') {
        return 'Czas wysyłki: 3-10 dni roboczych';
    }

    return $availability;
}

function custom_cart_availability($availability, $product_data, $cart_item) {
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    $quantity_in_cart = $cart_item['quantity'];

    // Wykorzystanie wspólnej logiki
    $custom_message = get_custom_availability_message($product, $quantity_in_cart);
    if ($custom_message) {
        return '<p class="backorder_notification">' . $custom_message . '</p>';
    }

    // Generalne ustawienia (jeśli nie znaleziono niestandardowego komunikatu)
    $stock_status = $product->get_stock_status();
    $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    if ($stock_status == 'instock') {
        return 'Na stanie: wysyłka w ciągu 48h';
    } elseif ($stock_status == 'onbackorder') {
        return ($stock_quantity > 0) ? 'Na stanie: wysyłka w ciągu 48h' : '<p class="backorder_notification">Czas wysyłki: 3-10 dni roboczych</p>';
    }

    return $availability;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_availability', 'custom_cart_availability', 10, 3);



function custom_backorder_notification($message, $product_id = 0, $quantity = 0, $order_id = 0) {
    if ($product_id === 0) {
        return $message;
    } else {
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

        $custom_message = get_custom_availability_message($product, $quantity);
        if ($custom_message) {
            return '<p class="backorder_notification">' . $custom_message . '</p>';
        }
    }

    return $message;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_availability_logic', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_availability', 'custom_cart_availability', 10, 3);
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', 'custom_backorder_notification', 10, 4);
```